# Delay updating a data value in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have the following input field with an error message below it:

```html
<div class="field" :class="{ error: !!errorMessage }">
  <input type="text" v-model="name" @input="checkName" />
  <div class="error-message">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
</div>
```

..and the `checkName` method, which .. well, checks the name:

```js
...,
methods: {
  checkName() {
    if(this.name.length < 3) {
      this.errorMessage = "Name too short";
    } else {
      this.errorMessage = null;
    }
  }
}
```

This all works fine, but I have an animation on `.field.error`, and I'd like to wait until it finishes before clearing `errorMessage`.

```css
.field {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 1s; // animate-out of error
}

.field.error {
  max-height: 3em;
  transition: all 0.6s; // animate-in to error
}
```

As it stands, `checkName` simultaneously (a) removes the `error` class on field and (b) clears `errorMessage`. Since `errorMessage` is cleared immediately, the animation is pointless (since the `<div>` is now empty..).

What I'd like is to have a 1 second delay between the removal of the `error` class from field, and `errorMessage = null` -- to give enough time for the outgoing error animation to complete.

Is there a way to do this without having to introduce additional `data` values? (I've shown the above for one field, but I have 4 fields in total)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `name` for toggling the class `error`.

Either like this:

```html
    <div class="field" :class="{ error: name.length < 3 }">
```

Or via a computed method:

```html
    <div class="field" :class="{ error: !nameIsValid }">
```

```
    computed: {
        nameIsValid() {
            return this.name.length > 2
        }
    }
```

I'd recommend the latter, especially if you'd want to use more than one error case (i.e. "name too long", "invalid characters", ...).

But you'd have to acknowledge the initial state. Since `name.length` is initially 0 you'd have the error being displayed initially - which is probably not wanted.

For validation (incl. error message handling) you could also use a plugin like [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/).